# How can we reload the sails console?

Tags: javascript, console-application, sails.js

How can we reload the sails console that has been running without exiting it, kind of like the reload command in the rails console. Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, 
there isn't a way to do this yet. Probably a good feature request to Trello..

See the contributing guide here:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md